# Is it available to change the webviewer button icon of 'annotationStyleEditButton' & ' annotationDeleteButton'

Tags: javascript, pdftron

I want to change the icon of 'annotationStyleEditButton' and 'annotationDeleteButton' to a self designed PNG, I would like to know is those buttons are available to change the icon?

I just found a method to change the Tools icon by using updateTool(), but seems we cannot change the 'style' and 'delete' button?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to change the icons but unfortunately, there are no APIs to do it. This is mainly due to the UI being completely open-source and open to everyone to customize and also contribute to. You are free to clone, download, or fork our repo here: [WebViewer UI Repo](https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-ui). You will need some knowledge of React (and maybe some redux) but it should be relatively easy to pick up.

To change the icon, you will have to change the `img` property of the `ActionButton` to use your images in the `AnnotationPopup` component. Alternatively, you could also just use HTML buttons and images if you would like. You can find a guide on advanced customizations here: [Advanced Customization](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/advanced-customization/). Once you do have the UI built, it will generate a `build` folder in the root directory. Simply copying this folder and replacing the one under `lib/ui` should update it to the one you just built.

As a last resort, you could always use some vanilla JavaScript to swap out the icons for your own. A query with the DOM can get you those elements to change:

```
document.querySelector('iframe[title="webviewer"]').contentDocument.querySelector('div[data-element="annotationStyleEditButton"]');
```

I would recommend sticking to the WebViewer UI method to avoid any unwanted results. It would also be better to own your UI as opposed to using this intrusive method.

Let me know if this helps!